# Does Python TestSuite leak memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, python-unittest

I run 3 Python UnitTest modules independently without problems. But when i package them into a TestSuite, the Tests hang arbitrarily. Does the TestSuite consume more memory ? Or does it leak memory ?

```
import unittest   
from testConfigurationLLC import testConfigurationLLC
from testRecordAllergyDataInOPPart1Of2 import testRecordAllergyDataInOPPart1Of2
from testRecordAllergyDataInOPPart2Of2 import testRecordAllergyDataInOPPart2Of2


class ConfigTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print 'stp'
        ##set up code

    def runTest(self):

        #runs test
        print 'stp'

def suite():
    """
        Gather all the tests from this module in a test suite.
    """
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(testConfigurationLLC('testConfigurationLLC'))
    test_suite.addTest(testRecordAllergyDataInOPPart1Of2('testRecordAllergyDataInOPPart1Of2'))
    test_suite.addTest(testRecordAllergyDataInOPPart2Of2('testRecordAllergyDataInOPPart2Of2'))
    return test_suite

mySuit=suite()


runner=unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(mySuit)
```

Comment: To get the formatting right, copy and paste the exact code into the question, then highlight it and hit the `{}` button. It's kind of hard to excuse bad indentation in Python questions. ;)

Comment: No, a TestSuite does not leak memory, but if your tests are not designed to clean up after themselves then running multiple tests can lead to problems.